# On the structure of outer automorphism group of $A_6$.

Tags: finite-groups

One knows $|Out(A_6)|=4$. Then $Out(A_6)$ is abelian. Furthermore it is cyclic group or element abelian 2-group.

QUESTION: IS $Out(A_6)$ cyclic group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups#Exceptional_cases),

$$Out(A_6) \cong C_2 \times C_2$$

Thus, it is not cyclic.